# Check if table exists in mysql

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL - check if table exists without using “select from”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/mysql-check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from)

Can I rely on this query to find out if tables in the specified database exists or there may be some restrictions?

```
SELECT
    `information_schema`.`TABLES`.`TABLE_NAME`
FROM
    `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE
    `information_schema`.`TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'my_database_name'
AND `information_schema`.`TABLES`.`TABLE_NAME` IN (
    'table_name',
    'table_name',
    'table_name',
    'table_name',
    'table_name',
    'table_name'
)
```

P.S.
I do not need to create a table, and just need to check whether it exists or not.

Comment: Answered already in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/mysql-check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from

Comment: That should do the trick.  Do you have some reason to doubt that it would work?

Comment: @EricPetroelje I think that this only works in mysql > 5

Comment: @Kirix - you are correct.

Answer (score 8):

Or you could use this (longer query).

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'databasename'
AND table_name = 'tablename'
```

Comment: this is the better answer because it always returns something, either 0 or 1, rather than NULL

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE tablename;
```

As per OP's comment - Edit:

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b528/2)

Check the demo out. It shows a code like this:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'user%';
```

Results:

```
TABLES_IN_DB_2_8B528 (USER%)
user_images
users
```

Comment: i have an array of tables...

Comment: @Kirix - you could just do a plain `SHOW TABLES` and search through the list for the ones you are looking for.  A database shouldn't have *that* many tables that this would be a performance issue.

Comment: @Kirix you may use the `wildcards` with `like` operator ;) it works, please take a look at the reference demo provided.

Comment: @EricPetroelje is it possible in `SHOW TABLES` specify database? Be default i using other database.

Comment: @Kirix - yup, `SHOW TABLES IN database_name` should do it.

Comment: Well if you are uncertain of the full name of tables, you could simply use multiple `like` `wildcards` with `or`. e.g. `SHOW TABLES
FROM <yourdbname> WHERE Tables_in_<yourdbname> LIKE '%user%'`
`OR Tables_in_<yourdbname> LIKE '%img%';` [SQLfiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b528/13)