# use php and mysql to see if a table exsists

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with a php program and want to check if a table exists.  If it does exist, do nothing, if it doesn't create and populate the table. I ran across

```
if(mysql_query("DESCRIBE `table`")) {
    // Exists
}
```

but this only takes action if it does exist.  Would this

```
if(!mysql_query("DESCRIBE `table`")) {
    // create and populate table
}
```

do what I am asking?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing won't work because the test is only testing the return value of the `mysql_query()` call, not the result of the query itself.

You need to query the tables with `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table'` and check the number of rows returned:

```
$db = new mysqli(...);
$result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table'");
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
   // create table
}
```

Note: mysql_*() is deprecated - you shouldn't use it for new code.

You'll find the MySQL reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html), and the PHP reference for `mysqli` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Take a look of this [mysql-check-if-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/mysql-check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from)

Comment: I noticed the different color on the word 'new'.  Do I need to include 'new' in that code?

Comment: I've used the OOP form of `mysqli`so you'll need `new` if you follow my code. You can use a procedural form - see the PHP manual for details.