# Check whether the table exists or not

Tags: php

```
$qry    = "SELECT * FROM nl_lang_var";
    if($qry === false)
        {
             $sql = "INSERT INTO  nl_lang_var set value='$value'        WHERE        name='$var' and langid=$langid"; }
            else {
 echo "already existed"; }
```

I want to know if the table *nl_lang_var* exists or not.

If it doesn't exist it must insert, otherwise give message.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/mysql-check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from

Comment: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES this will list all the tables in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i havent tried it if this will work, but i hope you can get some idea

```
SELECT count(table_name) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_name = 'nl_lang_var'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

```
SELECT 1 FROM nl_lang_var WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;
```

If the above query returns no error then table exists.

**Solution 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_NAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'nl_lang_var';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'nl_lang_var';
```

Or

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'nl_lang_var';
```

SHOW TABLE is fater than information_schema

But both are depended on the privileges to the connected user

[Ref](http://sjhannah.com/blog/?p=205)