# check whether table exist

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to check whether a table exists in my database but I am always getting "You are in!" as output. The output of the if statement is not being displayed in the browser.

I appreciate any help.

```
  $con = new mysqli ( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'bustracker' );
    echo "You are in!";
             if($con->connect_errno){
        die ( "connection problem!".$con->connect_error);
             }

          //check whether route's table exists.
          $results = $con->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$route."'");

           if( ($results->num_rows) == 1){
             echo "Table exist";
           }else{
            echo "table does not exist";
           }
```

Comment: You have an error here: `$conn->connect_error;` need  `$con->connect_error`;

Comment: I think you have forget to close }

Comment: If you only get "You are in!" is because your connection doesnt error : all your other code is in the if ( $con->connect_errno ) block. So you never go throught it.

Comment: I have the close bace in the code below and I changed the typo and I am getting nothing

Comment: check value of $route weather its empty of a value

Comment: I dont have the table in my database.

Comment: @saty it has a value "Bus_4"

Comment: Bus_4 is a table is your database???

Comment: no it is not but I want to check whether does it exist or not and if it exits insert data otherwise create it.

Comment: @saty: do I have a problem with $route in the mysql statement? I mean tje way I included it in it

Comment: if Bus_4 table not exits then its go into else condition it means your code is working.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
<?php
 
$con = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bustracker');
echo "You are in!";
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    die("connection problem!" . $con->connect_error);
} else {
    $results = $con->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $route . "'");

    if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {
        echo "Table exist";
    } else {
        echo "table does not exist";
    }
}
```

Comment: Very bad practices in the conception AND the code (avoir @ for ignoring errors...)

Comment: if i remove @ then also this code will be execute.@David'mArm'Ansermot

Comment: Yeah, but without @, if there is an error, you will be notified. WIth the @, the script will continue with error, it's bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 1 FROM tablename LIMIT 1;
```

If there's no error, table exists.

Or, if you want to be correct, use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'yourdb' 
AND table_name = 'your_table_name'
LIMIT 1;
```

Alternatively, you can use SHOW TABLES

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'your_table_name';
```

If there is a row in the resultset, table exists

Comment: Yes I found this answer somewhere too and I tried it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/mysql-check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from but no output

Comment: Yes you answer is right but the error in my code was the if statement which block the code. When I put the code in the else if-statement parts it works