# How to Use ALTER Table query with IF Condtion in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My requirement is to modify the column size of a table in MySQL table. I will use the ALTER statement to achieve this. But Before that I need to check whether the table is exists or not. If  the table exists then only I will use ALTER statement.

I tried so many ways. But not able to achieve this. Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: You need to run query like select 1 from tablename limit 1 , to check if table exists. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/mysql-check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from

Comment: Look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972922/add-column-to-mysql-table-if-it-does-not-exist   see the answer with 71 upvotes (second answer).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have a built in way to do this.

One option is simply to run the `ALTER TABLE` statement, and ignore the `Table ... doesn't exist` error if the table does not exist.

Another option (if you are willing to install [common_schema](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema)) is to use QueryScript to wrap the `ALTER TABLE` command in a try catch and ignore the error if the table does not exist.

Something like this would work:

```
  call common_schema.run("
    try 
    {
      alter table sakila.film modify column title varchar(100) not null;
    }
    catch {}
  ");
```