# How to check if a table exists in a MySQL database using shell script?

Tags: mysql, shell

i am trying to check whether a table is empty or not using shell script
the code that i have is

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "mysql -u user -ppassword -hserver dbname -e 'select count(*) from test_dec;'" != 0 ];
then
        echo "table not empty"
else
        echo "table empty"
fi
```

but when i run this it always displays "table not empty" even if the output of the query is 0.

```
user@server$ ./table_check.sh
table not empty
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

This is my version of the script and it will first check if table exists and if yes will check if the table is empty.

### BASH

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prepare variables
TABLE=$1
SQL_EXISTS=$(printf 'SHOW TABLES LIKE "%s"' "$TABLE")
SQL_IS_EMPTY=$(printf 'SELECT 1 FROM %s LIMIT 1' "$TABLE")

# Credentials
USERNAME=YOUR_USERNAME    
PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD
DATABASE=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME

echo "Checking if table <$TABLE> exists ..."

# Check if table exists
if [[ $(mysql -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -e "$SQL_EXISTS" $DATABASE) ]]
then
    echo "Table exists ..."

    # Check if table has records    
    if [[ $(mysql -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -e "$SQL_IS_EMPTY" $DATABASE) ]]
    then
        echo "Table has records ..."
    else
        echo "Table is empty ..."
    fi
else
    echo "Table not exists ..."
fi
```

### USAGE

First before using this script you need to replace **YOUR_USERNAME**, **YOUR_PASSWORD** and **YOUR_DATABASE_NAME** with the corresponding values. Then:

```
# bash SCRIPT_NAME TABLE_TO_CHECK
  bash my_script my_table
```

where **SCRIPT_NAME**( *my_script* ) is the name of the file holding the above script content and **TABLE_TO_CHECK**( *my_table* ) is the name of the table that you want to check for.

### EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
Checking if table <my_table> exists ...  
Table exists ...   
Table is empty ...
```

### COUPLE OF WORDS ABOUT THE CODE

Store the first argument from the command line in variable `TABLE`

```
TABLE=$1
```

---

Prepare two variables that will hold the SQL queries used to check.
Note that `printf` is used to insert the table name in the variables, because `$('SHOW TABLES LIKE "$TABLE"')` is not going to work.

```
SQL_EXISTS=$(printf 'SHOW TABLES LIKE "%s"' "$TABLE")
SQL_IS_EMPTY=$(printf 'SELECT COUNT(*) as records FROM %s' "$TABLE")
```

---

Check if table exists. `SHOW TABLES LIKE "table_name"` will return empty string if the table does not exist and the `if statement` will fail. Usage of the `$` like `$(echo 1 + 2)` means - evaluate whatever is inside the parentheses and return that as a value.

```
if [[ $(mysql -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -e "$SQL_EXISTS" $DATABASE) ]]
```

---

Finally we check if table is empty. Using the previous approach. Basically we check if MySQL will return empty string (*for empty tables*), otherwise the query will return some text as a result and we can consider the table not empty.

```
if [[ $(mysql -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -e "$SQL_IS_EMPTY" $DATABASE) ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
if [ $(mysql -u root -p -e \
  "select count(*) from information_schema.tables where \
     table_schema='db_name' and table_name='table_name';") -eq 1 ]; then
echo "table exist"
   exit 1
else
   echo "table doesn't exist"
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I think below will do your work,

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(mysql -u user -ppassword -hserver dbname -sse "select count(*) from test_dec;") -gt 0 ];
then
        echo "table not empty"
else
        echo "table empty"
fi
```

***3 changes from your script,***

1. enclose whole mysql statement part inside `$(..)` `-->` to make `LHS` the result of what goes inside `$(...)`
2. change `-e` to `-sse` in mysql connection statement `-->` to get only result of query to output without header and table structure.
3. Change `!=` to `-gt` `-->` operator for integer comparison in bash

Comment: it runs but gives me an error line 3: [: -gt: unary operator expected

Comment: Are you sure , you have used `-sse` , and output is `count(*)` .

Comment: Happy to hear . (Y).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when testing if we need to re-import a database.

```
databasename="mydatabasename";
tablename="tableweneed";
dbhost="localhost";
username="user";
password="password";

dbtest=$(mysql -h ${dbhost} -u ${username} -p${password} -s -N -e "select count(*) as tablecount from information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='${databasename}' and table_name='${tablename}'")

if [ "$dbtest" == 1 ]; then
    echo "Database is ok"
else
    echo "Database is being re-imported"
    mysql -h ${dbhost} -u ${user} -p${password} ${databasename} < /somefolderonmysystem/importdb.sql
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few different methods, this is what we used:

```
if [[ $(mysql --execute "SHOW TABLES FROM ${DB_NAME} LIKE '${DB_PREFIX}options';") -gt 0 ]]; then
```

...and yes, we define `mysql` as a function earlier in the script, and the database name and database prefix are also defined in a configuration file (this is part of our SlickStack project).

```
function mysql {
    command mysql --user=root --host=localhost --protocol=socket --port=3306 --force "$@"
}
```

You can change the name of this function in your bash script as desired.

Example: https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/bash/ss-install-wordpress-config.txt