# PDO -> if(table exist)

Tags: pdo

```
try {
    $query = $pdo->query("SELECT 1 FROM `classes` LIMIT 1");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $query = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TABLE `classes`(
    `ID_class` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(`ID_class`))");

    $query->execute();
}
```

Hello.

It doesn't catch, if the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work because, according to the [PHP documentation (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php):

> #### Return Values
>
> **PDO::query()** returns a PDOStatement object, or **FALSE** on failure.

So you either need to test if `$pdo->query("SELECT 1 FROM 'classes' LIMIT 1")` returns `false` or an alternative like [checking if a table exists without using 'select from' (stackoverflow.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from).

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with the PDO ATT_ERRMODE set to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.

```
$user = 'test';
$pass = 'test';
$opt  = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

$db   = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8' ,
                                    $user ,
                                    $pass ,
                                    $opt
                                    );


try {
    $query = $db->query("SELECT 1 FROM `classes` LIMIT 1");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $query = $db->prepare("CREATE TABLE `classes`(
    `ID_class` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(`ID_class`))");

    $query->execute();
}
```