# List All Dropped Databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to confirm if a particular table ever existed on our SQL Server. Is there an existing script or method one can use to list all dropped databases in an SQL server?

Comment: There's an article discussing this here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/09/12/sql-server-who-dropped-table-or-database/

Comment: Maybe this post is useful for you: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/check-if-table-exists-without-using-select-from)

Comment: This question is better suited for dba.stackexchange.com. DBAs handle such problems every day and know what works, what doesn't and how far back you can check. Devs have to google for this, unless they had to fix that problem at some point

Comment: Dropped tables or dropped databases? Anyway, you can pick up these events from the default trace, if they happened recently enough. See [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186) for a start.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in report you can access through SSMS called Schema Changes History.  You can run this to find what you're looking for.