# How to print mysql error code number if exception occured, While using Jdbctemplate in spring core java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am using JdbcTemplate and trying to create a table if not exist by checking MySQL error code 1146 But I am not able to check the error code.

Comment: Don't use error to detect if table existed, i.e. don't use exception for flow control. *Check* if table exists before trying to use the table. See [Check if table exists without using “select from”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8829102/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for answering but I need to run "SELECT" query every time before insert while I need to create table query once. Is there any alternate way to do the same.

Comment: So what's the problem in detecting the *first* time you run select query?