# Liquibase YAML - Preconditions

Tags: sql, spring-boot, liquibase, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to [check if a table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829122/2147481), then execute a changeset. But it seems the [precondition](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html) is not executed properly. Any suggestions on how to check if table exists and execute a statement?

**Liquibase Script:**

```
databaseChangeLog:
- preConditions:
  - onFail: MARK_RAN
  - sqlCheck:
      expectedResult: 1
      sql: SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = TABLE_MAY_NOT_EXIST
- changeSet:
    id: 1001001
    author: upgrade_author
    changes:
    - sql:
        sql: UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COL_A = (SELECT TOP 1 COL_A FROM TABLE_MAY_NOT_EXIST ORDER BY COL_A DESC)
        stripComments:  true
```

**Error Log:**

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table "TABLE_MAY_NOT_EXIST" not found; SQL statement:
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COL_A = (SELECT TOP 1 COL_A FROM TABLE_MAY_NOT_EXIST ORDER BY COL_A DESC) [42102-197] [Failed SQL: UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COL_A = (SELECT TOP 1 COL_A FROM TABLE_MAY_NOT_EXIST ORDER BY COL_A DESC)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:356) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:57) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:125) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1229) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1211) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:600) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have missed out the properties file for liquibase, you can find the method to write the liquibase properties file [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html)

Also, changelog files can be created as explained [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog.html)